# php closure in anonymous function and reference &

Tags: php, closures, anonymous-function

I have:

```
function outside( $limit ) {

$tally = 0;

    return function() use ( $limit, &$tally ) {
        $tally++;

        if( $tally > $limit ) {
            echo "limit has been exceeded";
        }
    };
}

$inside = outside( 2 );
$inside();
$inside();
$inside();
```

Outputs: `limit has been exceeded`

My understanding:

1. on `$inside = outside( 2 );` this returns the anonymous function and
   assigns it to the variable`$inside`. The anonymous function uses the
   value of `$limit` (2) and `$tally` (0).
2. function `$inside()` is called. This increments `$tally` to `1` The
   value is remembered somehow and so is `$limit`. What is the purpose
   of the ampersand before `$tally`? I know it's used to create
   references but in this context it confuses me. How can this closure
   remember the value of `$limit`?

Any references to official documentation would help!

Comment: Now there's some interesting code! Not seen that stuff in a while.

Comment: I actually protest that this question is a duplicate. While it is very similar, this question focuses more about the variable being passed by reference rather than the usage of the `use` keyword itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anonymous functions are actually `Closure` objects in php. If you add `var_dump($invoke)` to your code, you'll see this:

```
object(Closure)#1 (1) {
  ["static"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["limit"]=>
    int(2)
    ["tally"]=>
    int(0)
  }
}
```

`use`'d variables are stored in the `static` array in the closure object. When you invoke the closure, these variables are passed to the function, just like normal arguments. Therefore, if you don't use a reference, they will be passed by copying and any changes to them in the function will have no effect.

Comment: How does the value of $limit persist in subsequent calls, when its not declared as a reference?

Comment: Oh ok so since its a static priperty of the closure object the value persist throughout subsequent calls? I think i undersrand better now.

Answer (score 4):

The `&` means you pass the argument by reference and not value. This means you can change the variable inside the function, and it will be remembered outside - not just in that function.

By assigning the function to `$inside`, you are effectively keeping the reference to the variable intact, so it will be remembered from call to call.

See [PHP: Passing by Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Comment: I thought inside functions the keyword, 'static' was used for 'remembering' purposes, not the ampersand for remembering

Comment: Yes, that would work, but the `&` means you can pass the variable from outside the function, such as a reference to an object, or a global value (which isn't the same variable each time), ie it has to be set to a variable outside the function.

Comment: You could also pass a variable by value (without the `&`) and then return that value from the function and set it to the same variable. That would be functionally the same. But if you needed a function to change two variables (for example) then this becomes more complicated.